# page redirect to home in IE8 when i use angularjs config

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
app.config(function($locationProvider) {
     $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

i am using this in one of my page ,But when that page load in ie8 it redirect to home page.
Other browser working fine (Stay on that page).

i am using Angularjs 1.2.17

Answer (score 1):

IE8 doesn't work with html5mode in angular. You've got to set it to html5mode(false); and use the /#/ to get it to work.